# Weird output when printing `NaN` with std::cout and a changed locale

Tags: c++, output, locale, nan

I am currently trying to build a simple console calculator in C++ and was thinking about what to do when the user types `0/0`. In my calculator I convert each number from the users input to a `double` and therefore get the division `0.0/0.0` which should result in `NaN`.

However when I try to output this to the console I am noticing some weird behaviors with a changed locale. With large results it is easier to read the number when there is a separator between every 3 digits so I originally changed the local to `en_US`, which would format me a number like `1234.56` as `1,234.56` which is indeed the wanted behavior. But with `NaN` as output it didn't quite work as I thought it would.

In the following sample code I use `std::sqrt(-1)` to get `NaN` as result since my compiler (MSVC) doesn't allow me to divide `0/0.0`. At first I don't specify a locale (which should give me the `"C"` locale if I am not mistaken, at least I got the same output with nothing vs `"C"`). After that I changed to locale to `""` and `"en_US"` which both gave me different output with some seemingly random seperators in between.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    //std::cout.imbue(std::locale("C"));
    std::cout << std::sqrt(-1) << std::endl;

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << std::sqrt(-1) << std::endl;

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US"));
    std::cout << std::sqrt(-1) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
-nan(ind)
-na.n(i.nd)
-na,n(i,nd)
```

For my calculator not to print some weird output I could just check if the value is `NaN` before outputting it, but I still wonder why `NaN` gets represented different (with some weird characters in between) depending on my locale.

Comment: This looks like an obvious bug in the C library.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah sorry about that I forgot to include it since it worked without anyways for me. It was probably included with `iostream` in my case. Just added it in case someone else wants to try it.

Comment: You should report a bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How and where would I do that?

Comment: Since you're using Visual Studio, there was a button somewhere in the menus. "Help->report bug", or something similar.

Comment: @Joel I didn't find a similar bugreport so [I wrote one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Surprising-output-with-difference-locale/10441413). You can login and vote for it if you want MS to pay more attention to it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for writing one. I already wrote one after posting this question but never updated this post. You can look at my answer to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Writing-NaN-to-the-output-stream-with-a/10410933) and this was indeed a bug in the standard library and will be fixed in a later version of Visual Studio.

> The bug was fixed and the fix is expected in VS 2022 17.8 Preview 2